# Paradox Database with BDE - Forcing changes to disk while database/table open

Tags: delphi, bde, paradox

We have a Paradox Database table that we want to mirror across the network using something like DSynchronize.

The issue that I am seeing is that Paradox through the BDE (Borland Database Engine) does not update the file system until the table is either closed, or some buffer its using gets full.

I have used a flush buffers call, which has no affect on the files on disk. Calling close on the table forces the update I am looking for, however is a very large sledge hammer to this issue.

Am I simply missing some BDE setting somewhere?

Lastly sharing this database over the network using the correct NetDir settings makes the change visible to another machine. The files still appear untouched. The two systems only have the NetDir folder and Data Folder shared. I simply don't understand how the changes can be getting across without the files being altered, which they don't appear to be.

Any tips would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try [dbiSaveChanges](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20563).

Comment: This is what FlushBuffers does internally, however I will give it a go calling it directly.

Comment: OK. I have found the answer to my question. Paradox/BDE is updating the disk files. Its just pre-allocating space in the files so it only has to "touch" them every now and then. This means any file system monitoring software will not see the changes being applied. Also the index and db files need to be copied otherwise your out of sync.